# How can i disable right click on GUI Button in Babylonjs?

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

What is happening now is that if someone clicks the button with the left click, then the same thing is happening with the right click But I don’t like this: Click only with left click, button not click with right click

```
BABYLON.GUI.Button.CreateSimpleButton
```

**You can see example below** If u click button with right click they also work but i dont want this i only want to click this button with left not right.

https://playground.babylonjs.com/#1R7VD2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    button.onPointerUpObservable.add(function(event) {
        if (event.buttonIndex == 2) {return; }
        alert("click on button working");
    });
```